# Set NTP Server and Client to use UTC time and not any other timezone

Tags: ubuntu, ntp

I need to know how to configure NTP server and Client to use UTC time and not any other NTP pool servers in Ubuntu 18

Comment: Time zone is not actually a thing NTP cares about. Please try to rephrase your question to what you're hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

The NTP protocol is specified to always distribute only the UTC time, no matter which timezone the NTP server is located in.

If a single server within a NTP pool would distribute a non-UTC time, it would show a significant difference compared to other servers in the same pool, and properly-configured NTP clients (= using more than two NTP sources) should automatically disregard it.

The NTP pool management system will also be performing sanity checks and removing from the pools any servers distributing wrong time (e.g. some non-UTC time).

Like @hspaans said, the system default timezone is a system-local thing that should have no effect at all on NTP. And if you need to use a non-default timezone for a specific user or process(es), you can use the TZ environment variable to specify any timezone you want.

Comment: @roaima ...but I've seen it sometimes take a while to happen, so I was uncertain whether those checks are automated or manual. Certainly it would make a great deal of sense to automate them. Thanks for filling in that detail, edited.

Comment: No worries - I run a couple myself, so I know (for sure) :-)

Answer (score 0):

NTP timestamps are an epoch since January 1st, 1900, and are based on the [UTC time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#cite_note-Mills2010-1) just as time maintained by the Linux kernel. The time zone setting of the system or user will display the local time in the correct time zone.

With `tzselect` or `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` on Debian/Ubuntu you can set the time zone for your system. Per-user or process basis you can overrule that by setting the TZ variable like `TZ=CET ls -l` or `TZ=UTC ls -l`. The latter examples will show you the same files but with timestamps for Amsterdam or London.